# Feignclient is not fetching the list of servers configured

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm using **Spring Boot 2.7.6** with **Spring Cloud 2021.0.5**,
My Feignclient is not fetching the list of servers configured in application properties, printing following lines in log,

```
o.s.c.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean   : For 'MY-SERVICE' URL not provided. Will try picking an instance via load-balancing.
```

Instead of the configured URL it is taking default url i.e., http://MY-SERVICE/.. But I'm not using eureka server.

Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(name= "MY-SERVICE", fallbackFactory = MyServiceClientFallbackFactory.class)
public interface MyServiceApiClient {
    ........
}
```

Aplication properties:

```
MY-SERVICE.ribbon.listOfServers=https://my-service-api.prod.cloud.net
```

Build.gradle

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
 implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient'
 implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Ribbon*** has been deprecated and is not included in the 2020.0.0 release train. ***Spring-Cloud-LoadBalancer*** is the alternative.

Updated my properties as following as per *spring-cloud-loadbalancer*:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.MY-SERVICE[0].uri=https://my-service-api.prod.cloud.net
```

Reference document to configure *spring-cloud-openfeign* : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/